# Exclude specified directory when using `find` command

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, find

I have a directory which contains a number of files (no subdirectories). I wish to `find` these files. The following gets me close:

```
$ find docs
docs
docs/bar.txt
docs/baz.txt
docs/foo.txt
```

I don't want the directory itself to be listed. I could do this instead:

```
$ find docs -type f
docs/bar.txt
docs/baz.txt
docs/foo.txt
```

Using a wildcard seems to do the trick as well:

```
$ find docs/*
docs/bar.txt
docs/baz.txt
docs/foo.txt
```

My understanding is that these work in different ways: with `-type`, we're providing a single path to `find`, whereas in the latter case we're using wildcard expansion to pass several paths to `find`. Is there a reason to favour one approach over the other?

Answer (score 1):

You have a UNIX tag, and you example has a *.   Some versions of find have a problem with that.
If the directory has no subdirectories.
FYI.

Generally the first parms to find has to be a directory or a list of directories

```
find /dir1 /dir2 -print
```

Find is recursive - so it will follow each directory down listing every thing, symlinks, directories, pipes, and regular files.  This can be confusing. -type delimits your search

```
find /dir1 /dir2 -type f -print
```

You can also have find do extra output example: have it rm files older than 30 days for example:

```
find /dir1 /dir2 -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

Or give complete infomation

```
find /dir1 /dir2 -type f -mtime +30 -exec ls -l {} \;
find /dir1 /dir2 -type f -mtime +30 -ls   # works on some systems
```

To answer your question: because find can be dangerous ALWAYS fully specify each directory , file type ,etc., when you are using a nasty command like rm.  You might have forgotten your favorite directory is also in there.  Or the one used to generate your paycheck.   Using a wildcard is ok for just looking around.

Using *

```
find /path/to/files -type f -name 'foo*'
```

-- tics or quotes around strings with a star in them in some UNIX systems.

Comment: “You have a UNIX tag, and you example has a *. Some versions of find have a problem with that.” Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: find * -type f   on Solaris and HPUX may give stat errors when it tries to stat a "directory" that is a really a regular file. * expands to any file names in the current directory.  Called globbing.  Use the * construct for file names .  Edit in answer --

Answer (score 0):

```
find docs -type f
```

will get you a listing of every non-directory file of every subdirectory of docs

```
find docs/*
```

will get you a listing of every file AND every subdirectory of docs